# In my adapter I cannot change a defined value in my onClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

in my adapter I have the problem that if I have defined a String before the onClickListener I cannot change it later in the onClickListener. I can set it to invisible which works perfect however I cannot change it.

I want that if a user clicks on the image, a second image should replace the first one, but I cannot either change the image in a imageview, I suggest that it is the same problem as with the String which I cannot change.

Thanks for any help!

```
    private List<cards> listItems;
    private Context context;


    public arrayAdapter(List<cards> listItems, Context context) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        final cards currentItem = listItems.get(i);

        viewHolder.name.setText(currentItem.getName());
        viewHolder.comment.setText(currentItem.getComment());


        Picasso.get().load(currentItem.getProfileImageUrl()).into(viewHolder.image);

        viewHolder.name.setText("this work"); // here it works

        viewHolder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               //Try this
                 currentItem.setName("New text");
                  notifyDataSetChanged();


               //viewHolder.name.setText("New text"); // this does not work
               // viewHolder.name.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); this does work
                Picasso.get().load(currentItem.getProfileImageUrl2()).into(viewHolder.image); // does not work
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView name, comment, howMany;
        public ImageView image;


        /**
         * @param itemView
         */
        ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            comment = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.commentText);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: you have to notify it

Comment: in onclick update the listItems with new image url and then use setnotifyDatachange

Comment: Okay thanks! But I did not understand exactly how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change value in you list at particular position and then  notifyItemChanged(position);
in your click event write this:

```
currentItem.setName("abc");
notifyItemChanged(position)
```

Comment: Yes thanks! But in this case the hole item is reloaded and I would prefer if only the name changes because if the item is reloaded the screen is white for some millisecond...

Comment: but in adapter if  you want to add/change/remove any items or change in list then you have to notify your adapter otherwise new value will not reflect in your view.

Comment: I do not want to change an item, I just want that the image in imageView is not longer my url1 but that my url2 is loaded into imageView if I click on the image.

Comment: if you want not reload entire list then you can use two imageView and when click on imageView1 then hide that and show new Imageview  is display url2. so in that you don't need to reload entire list.Try this one.

Comment: Also you have to manage one flag in your model class for manage visibility of imageView1 and imageview2.When you change imageview visibility then you have to change flag value as per then requirement.

Answer (score 3):

You should call `notifyItemChanged` with the corresponding position.

```
   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    final cards currentItem = listItems.get(i);

    viewHolder.name.setText(currentItem.getName());
    viewHolder.comment.setText(currentItem.getComment());


    Picasso.get().load(currentItem.getProfileImageUrl()).into(viewHolder.image);

    viewHolder.name.setText("this work"); // here it works

    viewHolder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           viewHolder.name.setText("New text"); // this does not work
           // viewHolder.name.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); this does work
            Picasso.get().load(currentItem.getProfileImageUrl2()).into(viewHolder.image); // does not work

   notifyItemChanged(position);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Okay thanks, but in this case everything is reloaded and not only the image. Is it not possible that only the image is changed without reloading the item?

Comment: Whenever a value is changed we need to re draw that item, `notifyItemChanged(position)` will only reload that specific item. Since you're using `Picasso` it might need a network request to complete.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but then the image will not change smoothly, because the hole item is reloaded and for some millisecond the screen is white

Comment: In that case, you should download all possible images first, otherwise this issue will occur.

Comment: Yes okay and even if I would download all possible images, how could I change them in the imageview without the notifyItemChanged()?

Comment: If you've two imageurl then use two imageview and call picasso method. but show only the desired view, then change the visibility accordingly

Comment: I tried that and it also works, however later the images for other items are at the wrong places. If imageView2 is visible and imageView1 invisible than other images are at the wrong places for other items...

Answer (score 0):

In the data model you have keep a variable which indicates the current profile image.

for a example

```
 class cards {
      String name;
      String comment;
      ....
      boolean profileImageChanged;
    }
```

then inside onBindViewHolder

```
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
           ....

           if(currentItem.profileImageChanged){
             Picasso.get()
             .load(currentItem.getProfileImageUrl()).into(viewHolder.image);
           } else {
             Picasso.get()
             .load(currentItem.getProfileImageUrl2()).into(viewHolder.image);
           }

            viewHolder.name.setText("this work"); // here it works

            viewHolder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   viewHolder.name.setText("New text"); // this does not work
                   // viewHolder.name.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); this does work
                   notifyItemChanged(position);
                }
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can go with this approach also.

@Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    final cards currentItem = listItems.get(i);

```
viewHolder.name.setText(currentItem.getName());
viewHolder.comment.setText(currentItem.getComment());


Picasso.get().load(currentItem.getProfileImageUrl()).into(viewHolder.image);

viewHolder.name.setText("this work"); // here it works

viewHolder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       ViewHolder viewNewHolder=viewHolder
       viewNewHolder.name.setText("New text");
```

Picasso.get().load(currentItem.getProfileImageUrl2()).into(viewNewHolder.image); 
        }
    });

}

I have used it its working.

*******All The Best*********